# Will a Fuji Finepix S4800 take much better pictures than my Galaxy S4 phone?

Tags: image-quality, cameraphones

Which Camera will take better pictures? The one in my Samsung Galaxy S4 phone or a Fuji S4800 camera?  I know the Fuji has better MP (16 vs 13) and much greater zoom but  I am still wondering if I really need to purchase the Fuji when I have the Samsung.  Will the pictures be that much better? Thanks a bunch for helping me.

Comment: I find that most cameras take better photos than those on camera-phones - they have more options, can focus further away, more stable and less blurry images, etc. For practical purposes most phone-cameras are best close up - like in [this post](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/12437/10590) showing a close view of my 'baked' raspberry pi...

Comment: Similar and still useful here: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16449/is-the-iphone-4s-camera-good-enough-to-serve-as-ones-everyday-carry

Answer (score 1):

The Fuji will take better pictures by a country mile.

It has larger (and better) lens elements, sensor and built-in stabilisation which will all contribute a lot to improving image quality.

But the Fuji will only help if it's with you - otherwise you'll have something else to dust and still be taking snaps on your phone.

Comment: Since I was unfamiliar with "a country mile", here is some info for others too: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32640/origin-of-the-term-country-mile