# What camera specifications best complement a smartphone?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera-recommendation, smartphone

I have a Galaxy S5 right now, but I was looking into buying a better camera that matched the features my camera does not have.

Specs:
**Primary**     16 MP, f/2.2, 31mm, phase detection autofocus, LED flash, check  quality
**Features**    1/2.6" sensor size, 1.12 µm pixel size, geo-tagging, touch focus, face/smile detection, panorama, HDR
**Video**   2160p@30fps, 1080p@60fps, 720p@120fps, HDR, dual-video rec., check quality
**Secondary**   2 MP, f/2.4, 22mm, 1080p@30fps, dual video call

Things I've Noticed:

- Bad in lowlight
- Some features can only have a couple values (Iso, video framerate,Exposure Value)

In addition to features / specs I should look for, any camera recomendations would be appreciated.

Comment: This is too broad for us to be able to give a useful answer - essentially any dedicated camera will be better than a smartphone camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many reasons why a dedicated camera can complement a standard smartphone camera of today. Some reasons include:

- Optical zoom
- Larger image sensor
- Better high ISO / low light abilities
- More powerful true flash units
- Dedicated physical buttons
- Different focal length lenses
- Better autofocus speed and accuracy
- Resolution/image quality/pixel pitch/etc.

Of course some smartphones have enhanced features that overlap what benefits would normally exist only for a dedicated camera, but the vast majority of smartphones today are lacking in these areas.

The reverse is also true, there are many reasons why smartphones excel vs a dedicated camera. A quick look at recent sales figures will make that obvious.  I have another answer along those lines here: https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/16451/4892